# Apache httpd.conf strange behavior and virtual host setup

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I want to setup a virtual host and couldn't.

Checking better, I discovered that the server always opens the index page from the root, no matter what it is in the httpd.conf file or even in the httpd-vhosts.conf file.

As a test I deleted everything from the httpd.conf file and saved it as empty file and restarted Apache. It still opens the index.php file from the root. So how does it know the root, if there's nothing in the config file, in the first place..?

I cleared the cache with htcacheclean, but same result.

If I setup a virtual host with root in a subfolder and access it at http://site1.localhost, it doesn't open the index from the site1 subfolder, but again only the one from the root.

More than that, instead of site1 I can type anything, literally, and it wouldn't give error, it will open the same index.php file in the root.

What could be the problem..?

Comment: are you 100% sure there is only one Apache on that server and that it is reading the conf files you're talking about?  Try putting a syntax error in the conf files and restart Apache then you will really know.  Are you 100% sure you are restarting the right Apache?  only guesses but had something strange like that happen awhile ago.  there may be another Apache running or you are restarting the wrong Apache etc

Comment: Yes, it reads the conf file, because if I rename it the server doesn't start

Comment: try posting the contents of your httpd.conf and related conf files

Comment: I want to post the content of httpd.conf file by "Adding Comment" but that is not possible because this system doesn't allow anything different than short comments like this....  how can I post?

Comment: edit your original question/post.

Comment: When I paste the system complains about code unformatted, it's terrible.

Comment: So please download from here:
https://www.mediafire.com/?44o7i7d1orgfrha

Comment: and what is in your  conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf?  and the "index page from the root" -- which file is that referring to?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/mySites/site1"
 ServerName romaniatabi.localhost
 ServerAlias romania.localhost
 
 <Directory "D:/mySites/site1">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</VirtualHost>

Comment: the above is the virtual host setup in httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: The "index page from the root"  is  D:/mySites/index.php

Comment: sorry the correct vhost code is this:

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/mySites/site1"
 ServerName site1.localhost
 
 <Directory "D:/mySites/site1">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
The server was working fine. It was that when I restarted it from shortcut in Programs, after making modifications in httpd.conf and other files, it was not actually restarting, like I believed.

I restarted it from the Services, and then it worked...  quite weird behavior..
Anyway, thanks for caring.